# Using Geocode Ruby Gem for User Address input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding

I've using the Geocode Ruby Gem to convert the users input of zip/country into a nicely formated location (eg. Los Angeles, CA, USA). I also want to use the geocoding in the future (just in case you wonder why I'm going to so much trouble to pretty up the format

I migrated a column "address" into the user database. now I'm getting stuck with the geocoding and don't know if it is because I didn't create a locations folder in the database rather than migrate the column with the user database.

**I'm getting a routing error: undefined method `geocoded_by' for #**

I'm new at all this so I'm sorry if I'm not making any sense.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :latitude, :longitude

 geocoded_by :full_address
 after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed? 
end
```

Here's my controller:

```
def full_address 
  @user = User.find(params[:address])
  Geocode.serach("@user")
end
```

Changing my location.rb to the following:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
extend ::Geocoder::Model::ActiveRecord 

  attr_accessible :address, :latitude, :longitude

  geocoded_by :address_for_geocode 
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude 
end
```

Results in the following error:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant Location::Geocoder

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Comment: I would say your gem is not loaded, can you initiate Geocoder.search("1 Twins Way, Minneapolis") for instance. Try to comment out geocode_by and line below to see what is other error.

Comment: I agree, it sounds like the gem isn't loading. Did you run `bundle install` after adding it to your Gemfile?

Comment: I definately installed the gem. However, what you are both saying makes absolute sens. I'll do an update and install to make sure and I'll follow @milan's advice and comment out the geocode_by code as a test.

Comment: I've confirmed that Geocoder '1.1.1' is isntalled. I've added some additional comments to my original post in line with what @MilanJaric recommended.

Comment: you've got a typo in your controller: Geocode.serach("@user")

Answer (score 1):

You are getting Routing Error since you didn't understand what to change and how in code.

First

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :address, :latitude, :longitude
  # comment this out! => Geocoder.search("New York, NY, USA")
end
```

in your controller method, just try to execute

```
def full_address 
  @user = User.find(params[:address])
  render :text => Geocoder.search("New York, NY, USA").inspect.to_s
end
```

you will get either error (if gem is not loaded in your app) or some result.

Lets clear this out before we try anything else.

Run aaplication again and execute that route for **full_address** controller action

BTW, you can try all in rails console

> /path/to/project# rails c
>
> irb> Geocoder.search("New York, NY, USA")

#### Update

try to include geocoder in Loacation model

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ::Geocoder::Model::ActiveRecord

  geocoded_by :address_for_geocode
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
end
```

I just checked source code in their git repository, they are not extending ActivRecord::Base so you have to do it manualy!!!

Comment: It works in the console! @MilanJaric I followed your instructions, but don't see where it is going to output the results. If I leave my locations.rb file with only `attr_accessible :address, :latitude, :longitude` and add the controller method I don't get any errors. But, as soon as I add back in `geocoded_by :full_address` I run into a problem.

Comment: I'm looking at your code in question, seams to me geocoded_by is in Location model and you are trying to geocode User model. If I'm not wrong, that "geocode_by" should be in User model. Make sense?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake with the text. it is actually in my locations model. I've added the additional text from your update and still get the same issue.

Comment: damn :: in front of Geocoder module name :) now it should work, and if don't please `require 'geocoder/models/active_record'` above Location model

Comment: Now I get an `undefined method 'key?' for nil:NilClass` error

Comment: its something with your project setup, I doubt that Geocoder gem is that much broken! It's hard to tell without reviewing your whole project

Comment: thanks for your time and effort. I know it's user error. I'm biting off more than I can chew here and need to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your controller

```
def full_address 
  @user = User.find(params[:address])
  Geocode.serach("@user")
end
```

it should be

```
def full_address 
  @user = User.find(params[:address])
  Geocode.search("@user")
end
```